# Firestore snapshots.map(_transform) has no data in StreamBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Flutter project that uses Cloud Firestore. In one of my widgets, I have a StreamBuilder that ideally reads snapshots from the database. In theory, my API for reading from a remote server should be abstract enough to swap Firestore out with a different implementation.

```
class Database {
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> get snapshots => Firestore.instance.collection('entires').snapshots();

  Stream<List<String>> get entries => snapshots.map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents.map((document) => document.data['name']).toList());
}
```

If my StreamBuilder uses `snapshots`, then `AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>` has data (`hasData` returns true).

If my StreamBuilder uses `entries`, then `AsyncSnapshot<List<String>>` will never have data (`hasData` returns false)---even if I successfully printed out what the data is (my return result is a populated list of strings).

I hope to keep my `Database` interface free of Firestore. So, my question is: why does StreamBuilder's AsyncSnapshot return nothing even if I have data?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the issue revolves around `snapshot()` sending data off immediately.  I managed to create a work around by creating a class that wraps my Firestore collection.

This wrapper has its own `StreamController<T>` where T is the non-Firestore (abstract across multiple backend implementations) data type that I want to return.

The wrapper will listen on the necessary Firestore snapshots on construction. The latest snapshot result is cached. My `StreamBuilder` can then use both the internal `StreamController.stream` and the cached snapshot data for its construction.

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: _wrapper.stream,
  initialData: _wrapper.latestData,
)
```

This works for now, but has the side effect of continuously listening on `snapshots` indefinitely. I'll have to update my wrapper to stop listening on snapshots when not necessary (no subscribers) and re-listen when there are new subscribers, or simply use a mapping of the snapshot stream.